# How to filter Prisma query results based on a related model's property?

Tags: javascript, sql, one-to-many, prisma

I am using Prisma to query for posts and their associated reports. I want to retrieve only the posts that have a number of reports exceeding a certain threshold. Currently, I'm manually filtering the results after executing the Prisma query using the following code:

```
const posts = await prisma.post.findMany({
  include: {
    reports: true,
  }
});

const postsExceedingReportThreshold = posts.filter((post) => post.reports.length >= config.reportsToHidePost);
```

However, this approach feels redundant and inefficient. I've heard about Prisma extensions and the ability to write custom queries. Would using a Prisma extension be a suitable solution for this scenario? If so, how can I implement it to efficiently filter the posts based on the number of reports they have?

I would appreciate any guidance or alternative approaches to achieve a more optimal solution. Thank you!